# Bower script path reference

Tags: javascript, bower

If I install jquery using bower, the jquery.js file ends up in

```
bower_components/jquery/jquery.js
```

To then use jquery in my html file, do I just do

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.js">
```

?

Or is there a step that I am missing that builds and moves these installed packages into /lib or something.

Comment: Yeah that looks correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll just need to make sure that the `src` is relative to where your HTML file is located in your directory structure. Once you can confirm this, there is all that is to it.

You can also confirm that jQuery loaded correctly in Chrome Dev Tools (Open up your HTML file and open up the JavaScript console - Hamburger Icon > More Tools > JavaScript Console).